# Checking against existing data before selecting

Tags: sql, ms-access

The end result is that I want to create a file from a query that I can then use to do an Import into another dB.  I have Product Numbers (ITEM_NO) that can have two associated Barcodes (BARCOD).  I want to make sure that barcodes provided by TABLE_2 is not already in TABLE_1 (because sometimes there are)

**TABLE_1 (existing barcodes)**

```
ITEM_NO | BARCOD
-----------------
  001   |   A
  001   |   B
  002   |   C
  003   |   E
  003   |   F
  004   |   G
  005   |   I
```

**TABLE_2 (new barcodes)**

```
ITEM_NO | BARCOD
-----------------
 001    | B
 002    | D
 003    | F
 004    | H
 005    | J
```

So my desired output file would be

```
ITEM_NO | BARCOD
-----------------
 002    | D
 004    | H
 005    | J
```

For a starting point I have:

```
SELECT TABLE_1.ITEM_NO, TABLE_2.ITEM_NO, TABLE_1.BARCOD, TABLE_2.BARCOD
FROM TABLE_2 INNER JOIN TABLE_1 ON TABLE_2.ITEM_NO=TABLE_1.ITEM_NO
WHERE TABLE_1.BARCOD<>TABLE_2.BARCOD
ORDER BY TABLE_1.ITEM_NO
```

but this doesn't work because it compares Row 1 Table 1 against Row 1 Table 2, sees that the BARCODs are different and includes it in the query ... a false positive.  What I guess I am looking for is a way to create a string from a subquery, like STRING_TEMP [1] = [A,B] (please excuse how I am displaying this, not sure what the proper convention would be), so a string based on the value for TABLE_1.ITEM_NO, then checking to see if that string contains the value for TABLE_2.BARCOD where TABLE_2.ITEM = TABLE_1.ITEM

Hope this is enough info to paint a clear picture of what I am trying to do ... thanks in adnavce for any help provided,

Jordie Fike
www.kittyhawk.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, BARCOD
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE BARCOD NOT IN
    (SELECT BARCOD FROM TABLE_1)
```

Comment: this is the one that put me on the right path, I left out that only BARCODS come along where TABLE_1.ITEM_NO = TABLE_2.ITEM_NO (so in my example add rows 6|L and 7|N, and since there is not 6 or 7 in T1, we discard those rows)  

this is what did it for me
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_2.ITEM_NO, TABLE_2.BARCOD, TABLE_1.ITEM_NO
FROM TABLE_2 INNER JOIN TABLE_1 ON TABLE_2.ITEM_NO=TABLE_1.ITEM_NO
WHERE TABLE_2.BARCOD NOT IN
    (SELECT TABLE_1.BARCOD FROM TABLE_1)
ORDER BY TABLE_2.ITEM_NO;

sorry, can't format comments

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE ITEM_NO IS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_NO FROM TABLE_2)
ORDER BY ITEM_NO;
```

This selects all data from `TABLE_1` that isn't already in `TABLE_2`.

If you want all data from `TABLE_2` that is not already in `TABLE_1`, just switch the statement around:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE ITEM_NO IS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_NO FROM TABLE_1)
ORDER BY ITEM_NO;
```

I hope that helps and is what you are after.